# how to create a new dataset from existing dataset by manipulating one of dataset column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Im very new to spark and scala, and im trying to create a new dataset B from an existing dataset A.

Dataset A has columns a, b, c - where I want Dataset B to have columns a, b, and d.

Column d should be a boolean, either `true` or `false`, depending on the values found in column c. So for example, lets say column c is a string - I want column d to be true if the string is greater than 10 characters, and false if the string is less than 10 characters.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? For example `withColumn` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use withColumn, length and drop for this. The length check will return a col of type boolean.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val dataJsonStr="""[{"a":1,"b":1.1,"c":"Morethan10chars"},{"a":2,"b":2.2,"c":"lesthn10"}]"""

val dataSetA = spark.read.json(Seq(dataJsonStr).toDS)
dataSetA.show(false)
+---+---+---------------+
|a  |b  |c              |
+---+---+---------------+
|1  |1.1|Morethan10chars|
|2  |2.2|lesthn10       |
+---+---+---------------+

val dataSetB = dataSetA.withColumn("d", length(col("c")) >= 10).drop("c")

dataSetB.show(false)
+---+---+-----+
|a  |b  |d    |
+---+---+-----+
|1  |1.1|true |
|2  |2.2|false|
+---+---+-----+

dataSetB.printSchema()
root
 |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: double (nullable = true)
 |-- d: boolean (nullable = true)
```